# Integrating Prolog CLP(FD) with C#

Tags: c#, prolog, constraints, clpfd

I've got a prolog code with constraints over finite domain and I would like to make some GUI for that. Nothing complicated, only displaying some text, click button and on that click the result would be displayed.
I preffer C# & Visual Studio.
Is there a way to do it? I found some examples integrating prolog with C#, but the major problem is that my code is with constraints and it seems to be the biggest problem to 'connect'/'convert' the prolog code to C#.

Answer (score 1):

[ECLiPSe CLP](http://eclipseclp.org) has a C/C++ interface for embedding the interpreter in your application: http://eclipseclp.org/doc/embedding/embroot.html

It appears that you can use C libraries from C#:

- [Use a C library from C# code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9093292/use-a-c-library-from-c-sharp-code)
- [Tips for using a C library from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10847370/tips-for-using-a-c-library-from-c-sharp)
- [How to use C-Library in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17745329/how-to-use-c-library-in-c-sharp)
- [Is it possible to call a C function from C#.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11425202/is-it-possible-to-call-a-c-function-from-c-net)

[SWI-Prolog](http://www.swi-prolog.org) has a C# interface: http://www.swi-prolog.org/contrib/CSharp.txt